# Django: ERROR: python setup.py egg_info Check the logs for full command output

Tags: django, ubuntu, deployment

I am newbie as developer and have developped a first project in Django

I try to deploy my project in a test server (Ubuntu 18.04.1 LTS (GNU/Linux 4.15.0-88-generic x86_64)) prepared by a sys admin in my team

Each time I try to install dependancies (pip install -r requirements.txt) it fail with the error below:

```
    ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1:
     command: /home/test/envs/envTbm/bin/python -c 'import sys, setuptools, tokenize; sys.argv[0] = '"'"'/tmp/pip-install-1uqfxt7j/psycopg2/setup.py'"'"'; __file__='"'"'/tmp/pip-install-1uqfxt7j/psycopg2/setup.py'"'"';f=getattr(tokenize, '"'"'open'"'"', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"', '"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, '"'"'exec'"'"'))' egg_info --egg-base /tmp/pip-install-1uqfxt7j/psycopg2/pip-egg-info
         cwd: /tmp/pip-install-1uqfxt7j/psycopg2/
    Complete output (7 lines):
    running egg_info
    creating /tmp/pip-install-1uqfxt7j/psycopg2/pip-egg-info/psycopg2.egg-info
    writing /tmp/pip-install-1uqfxt7j/psycopg2/pip-egg-info/psycopg2.egg-info/PKG-INFO
    writing dependency_links to /tmp/pip-install-1uqfxt7j/psycopg2/pip-egg-info/psycopg2.egg-info/dependency_links.txt
    writing top-level names to /tmp/pip-install-1uqfxt7j/psycopg2/pip-egg-info/psycopg2.egg-info/top_level.txt
    writing manifest file '/tmp/pip-install-1uqfxt7j/psycopg2/pip-egg-info/psycopg2.egg-info/SOURCES.txt'
    Error: b'You need to install postgresql-server-dev-X.Y for building a server-side extension or libpq-dev for building a client-side application.\n'
    ----------------------------------------
ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1: python setup.py egg_info Check the logs for full command output.
```

I did not understand what could be the problem...

Comment: Sorry, but did you actually read the error? **Error: b'You need to install postgresql-server-dev-X.Y for building a server-side extension or libpq-dev for building a client-side application.'**

Comment: I missed this line... but I not admin sys so